# How I can to process a nested xml tags with the help of JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jaxb

How can I to process such structure with the help of JAXB?
There is one parent root catalog and many other in it, that are keeping info about many objects (states, for example).

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <root>
        <states>
            <state>
                <name>Alabama</name>
                <id>al</id>
            </state>
            <state>
                <name>Alaska</name>
                <id>ak</id>
            </state>
            ...
        </states>
        <airports>
            <airport>
                ...
            </airport>
            <airport>
                ...
            </airport>
            ...
        </airports>
        ...
    </root>
```

In case states, I created class States:

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "root")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class States {
        @XmlElement(name="states")
        private List<State> states;

        public List<State> getBrokers(){
            return states;
        }

        public void setBrokers(List<State> states) {
            this.states = states;
        }
    }
```

and class State:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class State {
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private String id;
    public State(){}
    public State(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
}
```

But when I call the States object

```
public class JaxbParser {
    public Object getObject(File file, Class c) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(c);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        Object object = unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

        return object;
    }

    public void saveObject(File file, Object o) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(o.getClass());
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(o,file);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
    JaxbParser parser = new JaxbParser();
    States brol =  (States) parser.getObject(new File("C:\\Users\\...\\1.xml"), States.class);

    List<State> brokerList = brol.getStates();
    System.out.println(brol);
}
```

the stateList contains only one state with id and name equals null.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You will need to define a custom Xml Adapter.

Comment: And where do you iterate through the `List<State> brokerList` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws 
JAXBException {
 try {
    File file = new File("....xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = 
    JAXBContext.newInstance(Classname.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = 
     jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Classname  objectName = (Classname) 
    jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

    List<Classname> list =  objectName.getStates();
    int i = 1;
    for (State ans : list){
        .....
    }

 } catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I used a simular structure, I only forgot to add it to code, bu now you can see it. Problem is not in this, unfortunatelly.